# What is the best method to predict test data once I know the training data and training label

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

What is the best method to predict test data once I know the training data and training label(continuous variables), so that I can get smallest prediction error.

Comment: What exactly is the prediction error in this context? The squared distance from the true value? Would you like to penalize over estimation more than under estimation? In general, there isn't a "best method" as Abdulelah indicated. Also, I would consider using cross validation to find the best algorithm instead of just minimizing the testing error.

Comment: I mean that we have a data-set which divide into x.train, y.train and x.test, I wanna predict y.hat for the test data, thus the teacher will compare it with the y.test (which is known to the teacher) to get the prediction error (MSE) . my goal is to choose one method to get the best predicted data.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the "best method" hasn't been discovered yet. Weather if your target variable is discrete or continues, decision tree is arguably one of the best predictive models that is also relatively easy to pick for beginners. You can find out more on the different variants of decision trees [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning)